# TFS - How to replicate the MKS Checkpoint functionality

Tags: tfs, baseline, mks, mks-integrity

We have been using MKS for a few years and now a new project has started up and has to use TFS.

In MKS we can take a checkpoint (a baseline/snapshot) of a project and then create branches from that baseline if required, even at a later date after further checkpoints of that development line have taken place.

How can I replicate this in TFS?  Labels don't seem appropriate since they can be changed and I want the baseline to be a true snapshot of the development at a point in time.  Changesets, as far as I understand, are just used to record changes to artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

I think Changesets are what you want to use.  Though a changeset does identify a specific set of code changes, when you perform operations within TFS based on a changeset, TFS usually interprets it as "all changes up to and including changeset XXX."

So, let's say you ask to branch at changeset `12345`.  TFS will get all files that are associated with a changeset less than or equal to `12345`-- even if they aren't part of `12345`.

Another option you can do is branch based on a specific date/time.  For example, if you had a major release on June 1st at 11:00AM, you can simply branch all code from that specific date and time.

All that being said, in our organization, we use labels.  Yes, labels can be moved, but that's not necessarily a bad thing, as it lets you account for mistakes.  For example, let's say we have a label: `ProdMove_June`.

Some time after the June release, we realize that, due to a failure of process, a configuration file was not included in TFS (or the file was deployed from TFS, but needed to be changed outside of the SCM process to respond to an emergency).  We then move this file into TFS and need to label it for all future branching.  If that's the case, then all we need to do is move the label on that single file.

In my opinion, all three of these approaches are valid, and we actually use all three within our organization for building, branching, and getting code.  I would suggest that you arm yourself with all three of these on your utility belt and use them where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a branch and then lock the branch.  Locking a branch makes the branch read only.